# How to apply template context processor only for authenticated users in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a context process that calculates notifications for users and contians costly queries:

```
def notifications(request):     
    if not request.user.is_authenticated(): 
        c = {}
        c['num_alerts']= 0
        return c 

    else:
        alerts = []
        uid = request.user.id
        #Calculate number of notifications for a user
```

In the `settings.py` I have:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.template.context_processors.debug",
"django.template.context_processors.i18n",
"django.template.context_processors.media",
"django.template.context_processors.static",
"django.template.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
'postman.context_processors.inbox',
'myproj.context_processors.notifications', #<This is the context processor
)
```

Most of the requests are from unauthenticated users. So I'm wondering how can I exclude them from the `notifications`?

Maybe using template context_processor is not the best idea in this case? If so, what is the better alternative?

Comment: Are you sure that [`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) is the problem? It sounds more likely to be the "calculation"

Comment: @Sayse, no, I'm not sure. So I rephrased my question. Thanks

Comment: The methods for `is_authenticated` literally only return [true](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L89) or [false](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L444), So your issue is somewhere else

Comment: @Sayse although that's true, if `request.user` has not previously been accessed anywhere before in that request it will be a [SimpleLazyObject](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L22), so calling `is_authenticated` will trigger the actual db query; that could be what OP is seeing. However that query needs to be done somewhere; the cost is inevitable.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Sure, in this case however, the [postman context_processor](https://github.com/rpgplanet/django-postman/blob/master/postman/context_processors.py) at least has already accessed the `is_authenticated`/user

Comment: show us the code for the calculation... likely a quick query.  Other things to consider is using memcached to cache the calulated response for even a short period of time can reduce load